# Issues with already defined PK's: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list

Tags: sql, oracle

I am aware this error is telling me I shouldn't have a FK of something that isn't a PK, but I think that's not my case and I haven't found a way around it, so here's my code:
I have this `ENTITY` table

```
CREATE TABLE ENTITY(
    entity_id VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(30)
);
```

No problem there, the problem comes when I try to create another table with `entity_id` as a FK, as such:

```
CREATE TABLE EXPORTER(
    exporter_id VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(30),
    FOREIGN KEY (exporter_id) REFERENCES ENTITY(ENTITY_ID)
);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what database are you using?

Comment: Are you using a case-sensitive collation? Try `REFERENCES ENTITY(entity_id)`

Comment: I'm using an oracle database provided by my class (we're using SQLDeveloper). Also, case is not the issue, I already tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
CREATE TABLE ENTITY(
    entity_id VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(30)
);

CREATE TABLE EXPORTER(
    exporter_id VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(30),
    CONSTRAINT FK_exporter_id
    FOREIGN KEY (exporter_id)
    REFERENCES ENTITY(entity_id)
);
```

Comment: You needed the keyword CONSTRAINT and a unique name to give the FK relationship.  All Good.